# REST API design for a Alert system

Tags: rest, api-design

Im new to REST API design and I was wondering how one goes about designing for a problem defined as below. I have also outlined what I have in mind currently but obviously I see many problems with it

- A `Cluster` has `Alerts`
- `Alerts` are instances of `Alert_Type`
- An `Alert_Type` can be assigned to `Cluster(s)`. In this case the `Cluster`
  is Registered for `Alerts` of `Alert_Type`
- An `Alert_Type` can also be assigned to no `Cluster`
- When an `Alert` of instance `Alert_Type` occurs in a `Cluster`, some action
  occurs if and only if `Alert_Type` is registered with a `Cluster` and `Alert_Type` exists

For purposes of this question I am concerned with the REST API design and routes for the `Alert_Type` Object and `Cluster` Object

These are a subset of REST actions I can perform on `Cluster` Object:

**POST**: Create a new `Cluster` Object. In the object a field called `registered_alerts` could contain the `Alert_Type` objects registered for this `Cluster`

**DELETE**: Delete an existing `Cluster` Object

**GET** (on /alert_types) : Will return a list of `Alert_Type` objects registered with this `Cluster`

These are a subset of REST actions I can perform on `Alert_Type` Object:

**POST**: Create a new `Alert_Type` object.

**DELETE**: Delete an existing `Alert_Type` object

**GET**: Get an existing `Alert_Type` object

Now my questions:

1. Obviously I need to tie the `Cluster` and `Alert_Type` objects - I
   know its not good design to duplicate the `Alert_Type` objects in
   the `Cluster` objects. So maybe I should generate an id for each
   `Alert_Type` object and require that the `Cluster` POST send an id
   instead? And then maintain a list of id's in the `Cluster` Object
2. If the `Cluster` POST has a bunch of `Alert_Type` ID's some that are
   valid and some that are not, how do I handle that?
3. The unique id for an `Alert_Type` must be generated at the server,
   and returned back in the response of the POST of `Alert_Type` -
   whats the correct way to do this in a REST compatible way ?
4. Do you think it would be required to even hold the `Cluster` ID's in
   the `Alert_Type` objects? The only reason i can see the need for
   this is when an `Alert_Type` is deleted - and then that should
   update the `Cluster` objects that are watching for this `Alert_Type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to give you a response for every point:

1. Yes you should use the id in the Cluster object.
2. You must return an error end don't save anything.
3. I should return the id of the created Alert_Type in the POST response (eg. json {'id': 'theId'}).
4. It depends on the db implementation: if you can simply retrive the Cluster connect to the deleting Alert_type i suggest you to not keep inverse connection because if you do that you have one more field to manage.

Hope can i help.